# Can I place text into 2 boxes rather than 1 using AJAX

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I have made a simple html page which fetches info from one of my databases' tables and pastes it into a text box. It does this by connecting to a PHP via an AJAX function which handles the request.

What I am wondering is whether this data could be placed into two text boxes, rather than just the one. I don't know how to go about doing this, because in my code I have to state a single text box, would I have to make separate functions for each text box to get it to work or is there a simpler solution?

HTML PAGE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDetails(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("Text1").value=""; 
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Text1").value=xmlhttp.responseText; // here is why it only      goes into "Text1"
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getDetails.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<!--here a user enters an "RFID" and the details are returned into "Text1"-->
<input type="text" name="RFID1" value="" onKeyup="getDetails(this.value)" /> 
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="Text1" />
<input type="text" id="TextScore1" name="TextScore1"/>
</form>

<br/>

<form>
<!--here a user enters another "RFID" and the details are also returned into "Text1"
(though I would like it to go to Text2 and TextScore2)-->
<input type="text" name="RFID2" value="" onKeyup="getDetails(this.value)" />
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="Text2"/>
<input type="text" id="TextScore2" name="TextScore2"/>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

PHP PAGE:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mssql_connect("SQL", "0001", "Password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
  }

mssql_select_db("database1", $con);



$sql="SELECT * FROM Scrabble WHERE RFID = '".$q."'";

$result = mssql_query($sql);


while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo $row['Tile'];

  echo $row['TileScore'];
  }


mssql_close($con);
?>
```

*note - My server uses MsSQL

Another question, as you can see in the HTML file, I have two forms, I need the same function to happen to both forms. Here I figure I'm probably going to have to create another PHP file to connect to for each form. But just to be sure I'm going to ask, is it possible to keep it in a single file and if so how you would go about it?

**EDIT** it seems I have confused some people, I don't want the text to be put into both text boxes, but actually split the results into the two text boxes. Such that "Text" would end up in the text box Text1 and TextScore would end up in the text box TextScore1

Comment: As a friendly aside, you might want to look into ways of working with PHP and MsSQL that don't expose you to SQL injection attacks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: You change the content of as many elements/inputs as you want. Just do it for each element as you already know it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this ?

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("Text1").value=response;
  document.getElementById("Text2").value=response;
}
```

For the second function, you can use the same PHP file . You may need to pass a querystring value to the PHP page when making the ajax call to determine, "from where this call came ".

something like

```
getDetails.php?from="userinfo"
```

and

```
getDetails.php?from="checkprice"
```

And in your PHP file , you can check the value of the query string varible and execute the approprate set of code. You may use if /switch etc there...

But i would prefer to separate the functionalities logically and keep it in separate files.

**Ex** : I will keep all user related functionalities in a `userajaxhelper.php` and keep my Order related functionalities in another file called o`rderajaxhelper.php`. This makes my code organised and clean.

**EDIT** : Just want to include Andy Hume's comment to my answer as it is in an important point. You should really make sure you are not going to be the victim of [SQL injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

Answer (score 0):

You've a codeline

```
document.getElementById("Text1").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

If you want to add same text to the box2

```
document.getElementById("yourSecondText").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

And if not the same then php should give answer in JSON format, with part1,.... separately.

As a response to ajax you should assign appropriate parts to its textboxes.

Sorry if i didn't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the results from PHP as JSON, see [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) and also send the correct header, content type application/json.

Then parse the JSON in your JavaScript using [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) and you'll be able to assign one key/parameter to the first field, the another to the other field.

```
...
$result = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result[] = $row;
}
mssql_close($con);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

and the JS (note: I haven't tested the JS code, but it should provide an example):

```
...
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

    document.getElementById("Text1").value = jsonObj.Title;
    document.getElementById("TextScore1").value = jsonObj.TileScore;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: You can do "whatever you want" when the response returns. You just need to figure out exactly what it is that you want to do and how that is achieved; the earlier answers already give good pointers. As a general notion, though, you might want to "scale down" to the barebones of the problem - get the pages you have as generic as possible so that it still does what you want.

Example of what you would might want to do (not tested, just something set up quickly, but you should do the point, I think)...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
            function doAjaxRequest() {
                // Set up Ajax-request, that will execute the
                // response it gets from the server "as is"...
                // Just what you were doing, but instead of
                // putting the response into textarea, execute it...
                eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        // --></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
            <textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
            <input type="button" onclick="doAjaxRequest();return false">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the serverside...

```
<?php
    // It doesn't matter which way you get the data, just... use it :-p
    echo('document.getElementById("txt1").value="Response 1";');
    echo('document.getElementById("txt2").value="Response 2";');
?>
```

Comment: sorry could you clarify what you mean for the "doAjaxRequest()" function - try to use the eval(xmlhttp.responseText); but I just get an error

Comment: Ok so I got the _eval(xmlhttp.responseText);_ to work but now in the php file I cant make it change the values of the text boxes with the fetched information. I always get "$Text is not defined" or something along the lines